# Convert tabular List data to Rowa in C#

Tags: c#

I am querying database to get Tabular data

```
ID   NAME
1     ABC
2     XYZ
3     IJK
4     LMN
5     OPQ
6     RSS
7     NTN
8     UPS
9     DHL
10    XXX   

I want this to convert it into following format to display in Grid

1  ABC    2 XYZ     3 IJK
4  LMN    5 OPQ     6 RSS
7  NTN    8 UPS     9 DHL
10 XXX


I want to Convert it into a List of Following Object

Class NewData
{
  Int Id1
  string Name1
  int id2
  string Name2
  int id3
  string Name3
```

}

Comment: Cool. So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just query it out with something like

```
Select C1.ID,C1.Name, C2.ID,C2.Name, C3.ID,C3.Name 
From MyTAble c1
Left Join MyTable c2 On c2.ID = (C1.ID + 1)
Left Join MyTable c3 On c3.ID = (C1.ID + 2)
Where ((C1.ID -1) % 3) = 0;
```

NB this works because your Ids are contiguous. If they weren't it would leave gaps.

Comment: It's helpful but i need this conversion in c#

Comment: So post what you've tried. There's loads of ways of doing this, I'm finding it difficult to accept you can't even come up with one.